# Creating a new line break in javascript function that is formatting images

Tags: javascript, css

I'm not a javascript dev, but I was given some code for debugging.  Please bear with me.  Basically, there is a .js CSS file set inside of an iOS module I'm working on.  The images are currently loading improperly, causing a horizontal scroll to be necessary.

Here is my code.  You can see the style is set to block for display, but that isn't giving the desired output.

```
function resizeImages(container, maxWidth) {
var images = container.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var img = images[i];

    var width = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(img, null).getPropertyValue('width'));
    var height = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(img, null).getPropertyValue('height'));
    if (width > maxWidth) {
        var ratio = maxWidth / width;
        img.style.width = (maxWidth - 30) + "px";

        // Some image heights are set to 'auto' so they do not need their height set
        if (height != 0) {
           img.style.height = parseInt(height * ratio) + "px";
        }
    }

    img.style.display = "block";
    img.style.marginLeft = "auto";
    img.style.marginRight = "auto";
   }
}
```

Is it possible to set the layout in this function, or am I going to have to find another way?

Thank you for any help

EDIT************* Printed out the html that was returned on the call and added what I could here

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/7.0.2.0/styles/jive-base.css" type="text/css"     media="all"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/7.0.2.0/styles/jive.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/7.0.2.0/styles/jive-content.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

<style>
/* Improve default page styles for mobile */
body { background-color: #FFFFFF; min-width: 100px; padding-top: 20px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;}
p {width: 98%; }
div.jive-rendered-content { width: 98%; }
.jive-rendered-content img.jive-image { margin: 5px; }

/* Remove link icons from inline links */
.jive-link-profile-small, .jive-link-socialgroup-small, .jive-link-community-small, .jive-link-blog-small, .jive-link-video-small, .jive-link-external-small:after, .jive-link-external-small, .jive-link-wiki-small { background-image: none; }

/* Remove underline from links after they're activated */
a:hover, a:active, a:focus { text-decoration: none; }

/* Hide unsupported Flash video content */
.jive-video-view, .jive-content-video { display: none; }
</style>
```

HTML I know this is ugly, but I tried to clean it up while leaving the meat.  My apologies.

```
<body><link rel="stylesheet" href="/7.0.2.0/styles/jive-base.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/7.0.2.0/styles/jive.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/7.0.2.0/styles/jive-content.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

<style>
/* Improve default page styles for mobile */
body { background-color: #FFFFFF; min-width: 100px; padding-top: 20px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;}
p {width: 98%; }
div.jive-rendered-content { width: 98%; }
.jive-rendered-content img.jive-image { margin: 5px; }

/* Remove link icons from inline links */
.jive-link-profile-small, .jive-link-socialgroup-small, .jive-link-community-small, .jive-link-blog-small, .jive-link-video-small, .jive-link-external-small:after, .jive-link-external-small, .jive-link-wiki-small { background-image: none; }

/* Remove underline from links after they're activated */
a:hover, a:active, a:focus { text-decoration: none; }

/* Hide unsupported Flash video content */
.jive-video-view, .jive-content-video { display: none; }
</style><!-- [DocumentBodyStart:e313f4cb-be82-4ce9-9325-7ec5d2d25b49] --><div class="jive-rendered-content"><p><p style="min-height: 8pt; padding: 0px;">&#160;</p><table border="0px" class="jiveBorder" jive-data-cell="{&quot;color&quot;:&quot;#3D3D3D&quot;,&quot;textAlign&quot;:&quot;center&quot;,&quot;padding&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;backgroundColor&quot;:&quot;transparent&quot;,&quot;fontFamily&quot;:&quot;Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,Lucida Grande,sans-serif&quot;,&quot;verticalAlign&quot;:&quot;baseline&quot;}" jive-data-header="{&quot;color&quot;:&quot;#505050&quot;,&quot;backgroundColor&quot;:&quot;#F2F2F2&quot;,&quot;textAlign&quot;:&quot;left&quot;,&quot;padding&quot;:&quot;6&quot;}" style="border: 0px solid #c6c6c6; width: 100%;"><tbody><tr><td style="border:0pxpx solid black;border: 0px solid #c6c6c6;padding: 2px;vertical-align: top;text-align: center;"><a href="https://ppppp.ddd.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/38-91630-522497/13672161_10157144798120367_1344748601_n.jpg"><img alt="13672161_10157144798120367_1344748601_n.jpg" class="image-1 jive-image" height="206" src="https://ppppp.ddd.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadImage/38-91630-522497/13672161_10157144798120367_1344748601_n.jpg" style="height: auto;" width="275"/></a></td><td style="border:0pxpx solid black;border: 0px solid #c6c6c6;padding: 2px;vertical-align: top;text-align: center;"><a href="https://ppppp.ddd.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/38-91630-522498/13689395_10157144799275367_1573986411_n.jpg"><img alt="13689395_10157144799275367_1573986411_n.jpg" class="image-2 jive-image" height="206" src="https://ppppp.ddd.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadImage/38-91630-522498/13689395_10157144799275367_1573986411_n.jpg" style="height: auto;" width="275"/></a></td><td style="border:0pxpx solid black;border: 0px solid #c6c6c6;padding: 2px;vertical-align: top;text-align: center;"><a href="https://ppppp.ddd.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/38-91630-522499/13706333_10157144800985367_1742170785_n.jpg"><img alt="13706333_10157144800985367_1742170785_n.jpg" class="image-3 jive-image" height="206" src="https://ppppp.ddd.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadImage/38-91630-522499/13706333_10157144800985367_1742170785_n.jpg" style="height: auto;" width="275"/></a></td></tr></tbody></table><p style="min-height: 8pt; padding: 0px;">&#160;</p><table border="0px" class="jiveBorder" jive-data-cell="{&quot;color&quot;:&quot;#3D3D3D&quot;,&quot;textAlign&quot;:&quot;center&quot;,&quot;padding&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;backgroundColor&quot;:&quot;transparent&quot;,&quot;fontFamily&quot;:&quot;Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,Lucida Grande,sans-serif&quot;,&quot;verticalAlign&quot;:&quot;baseline&quot;}" jive-data-header="{&quot;color&quot;:&quot;#505050&quot;,&quot;backgroundColor&quot;:&quot;#F2F2F2&quot;,&quot;textAlign&quot;:&quot;left&quot;,&quot;padding&quot;:&quot;6&quot;}" style="border: 0px solid #c6c6c6; width: 100%;"><tbody><tr><td style="border:0pxpx solid black;border: 0px solid #c6c6c6;padding: 2px;vertical-align: baseline;text-align: center;"><a href="https://ppppp.ddd.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/38-91630-522500/13705113_10157144798165367_204528607_n.jpg"><img alt="13705113_10157144798165367_204528607_n.jpg" class="image-4 jive-image" height="206" src="https://ppppp.ddd.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadImage/38-91630-522500/13705113_10157144798165367_204528607_n.jpg" style="height: auto;" width="275"/></a></td><td style="border:0pxpx solid black;border: 0px solid #c6c6c6;padding: 2px;vertical-align: baseline;text-align: center;"><a href="https://ppppp.ddd.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/38-91630-522501/13714428_10157148347660367_1956053232_n.jpg"><img alt="13714428_10157148347660367_1956053232_n.jpg" class="image-5 jive-image" height="206" src="https://ppppp.ddd.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadImage/38-91630-522501/13714428_10157148347660367_1956053232_n.jpg" style="height: auto;" width="275"/></a></td><td style="border:0pxpx solid black;border: 0px solid #c6c6c6;padding: 2px;vertical-align: baseline;text-align: center;"><a href="https://ppppp.ddd.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/38-91630-522502/13689832_10157144798095367_1657929227_n.jpg"><img alt="13689832_10157144798095367_1657929227_n.jpg" class="image-6 jive-image" height="206" src="https://ppppp.ddd.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadImage/38-91630-522502/13689832_10157144798095367_1657929227_n.jpg" style="height: auto;" width="275"/></a></td></tr></tbody></table><p style="min-height: 8pt; padding: 0px;">&#160;</p><table border="0px" class="jiveBorder" jive-data-cell="{&quot;color&quot;:&quot;#3D3D3D&quot;,&quot;textAlign&quot;:&quot;center&quot;,&quot;padding&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;backgroundColor&quot;:&quot;transparent&quot;,&quot;fontFamily&quot;:&quot;Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,Lucida Grande,sans-serif&quot;,&quot;verticalAlign&quot;:&quot;baseline&quot;}" jive-data-header="{&quot;color&quot;:&quot;#505050&quot;,&quot;backgroundColor&quot;:&quot;#F2F2F2&quot;,&quot;textAlign&quot;:&quot;left&quot;,&quot;padding&quot;:&quot;6&quot;}" style="border: 0px solid #c6c6c6; width: 100%;"><tbody><tr><td style="border:0pxpx solid black;border: 0px solid #c6c6c6;padding: 2px;vertical-align: baseline;text-align: center;"><a href="https://ppppp.ddd.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/38-91630-522503/13689795_10157148347775367_1926959939_n.jpg"><img alt="13689795_10157148347775367_1926959939_n.jpg" class="image-7 jive-image" height="400" src="https://ppppp.ddd.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadImage/38-91630-522503/13689795_10157148347775367_1926959939_n.jpg" style="height: auto;" width="300"/></a></td><td style="border:0pxpx solid black;border: 0px solid #c6c6c6;padding: 2px;vertical-align: baseline;text-align: center;"><a href="https://ppppp.ddd.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/38-91630-522504/13713516_10157148347865367_1911484589_n.jpg"><img alt="13713516_10157148347865367_1911484589_n.jpg" class="image-8 jive-image" height="400" src="https://ppppp.ddd.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadImage/38-91630-522504/13713516_10157148347865367_1911484589_n.jpg" style="height: auto;" width="300"/></a></td></tr></tbody></table></div><!-- [DocumentBodyEnd:e313f4cb-be82-4ce9-9325-7ec5d2d25b49] --><script type="text/javascript">

function formatBlogContent() {
var container = document.querySelector('body');
var maxWidth = document.body.clientWidth - 30;

// Size images to screen
resizeImages(container, maxWidth);

// Remove left/right padding
var items = container.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i];

    // Set the font size
    item.style.fontSize = "11pt";

    // Remove indentation
    var paddingLeftString = window.getComputedStyle(item, null).getPropertyValue('padding-left');
    var paddingLeftInt = parseInt(paddingLeftString);
    var paddingRightString = window.getComputedStyle(item, null).getPropertyValue('padding-right');
    var paddingRightInt = parseInt(paddingRightString);
    if (paddingLeftInt > 0 || paddingRightInt > 0) {
        item.style.paddingLeft = "0px";
        item.style.paddingRight = "0px";
        item.style.width = maxWidth - 50 + "px";
        item.style.marginLeft = "auto";
        item.style.marginRight = "auto";

        // Resize adjusted block level images
        resizeImages(item, (maxWidth - 65));
    }
}

// Remove tables that are larger than the content space
var tables = container.getElementsByTagName('table');
for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
    var table = tables[i];

    var tableWidth = window.getComputedStyle(item, null).getPropertyValue('width');
//        alert("width: " + tableWidth)
    if (tableWidth > maxWidth) {
        table.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        table.width = "98%"
    }
}

      // Adjust Links
    updateLinks(container)
}

  function resizeImages(container, maxWidth) {
var images = container.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var img = images[i];

    var width = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(img, null).getPropertyValue('width'));
    var height = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(img, null).getPropertyValue('height'));
    if (width > maxWidth) {
        var ratio = maxWidth / width;
        img.style.width = (maxWidth - 30) + "px";

        // Some image heights are set to 'auto' so they do not need their height set
        if (height != 0) {
           img.style.height = parseInt(height * ratio) + "px";
        }
    }

    img.style.display = "block";
    img.style.marginLeft = "auto";
    img.style.marginRight = "auto";
}
}

    function updateLinks(container) {
var links = container.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var link = links[i];
    var url = link.href

    // Test for link to profiles
    var peopleLinks = url.search(/\/people\//i);
    if (peopleLinks > 0) {
        // Move to next profile, leaving link active
        continue;
    }

    // Test for link to a blog
    var blogLinks = url.search(/\/blogs\//i);
    if (blogLinks > 0) {
        // Replace URL with AWB URL
        var awbURL = url.replace("https:","awbs:");
        link.href = awbURL;
        continue;
    }

    // Disable link
    link.href = "javascript:void(0)";

    // Set the text color to the same as the parent element so that user can't tell there's a link
    var parent = link.parentElement;
    link.style.color = window.getComputedStyle(parent, null).getPropertyValue('color');
}
}

// Kick off the formating process after the page load
formatBlogContent();

</script></body>
```

Comment: We would probably need more to answer this. A fiddle with the corresponding HTML and CSS might be helpful. And, as a remark, the `30` seems to be quite arbitrary, especially regarding the height is being calculated by `ratio`.

Comment: Just set a `max-width: 100%` in the CSS

Comment: Capping the max-width my work, but if `display:block` doesn't work then you probably have a bunch of wrapping elements in your HTML that you might want to clean up. What does the resulting HTML look like?

Comment: `max-width: 100%;` on the images and `overflow-x: none;` on the parent element should stop the horizontal scroll, without knowing more about the context.

Comment: I printed the html output and added it above.  It's being loaded from an API, and then reconfigured with the js and CSS I also included.  So, I'm not sure where to go with it.  Thank you for your replies

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using one of the comments as an answer.  The code looked like this in the css file

```
img {
max-width: 98%;
height: auto;
}
```